# How to match a specific character only if it is followed by string containing specific characters

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to replace slashes in a string, but not all of them - only the ones before first comma. To do that, I probably have to find a way to match only slashes being followed by string containing a comma.

Is it possible to do this using **one** regexp, i.e. without first splitting the string by commas?

Example input string:

```
Abc1/Def2/Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4
```

What I want to get:

```
Abc1.Def2.Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4
```

I've tried some lookahead and lookbehind techniques with no effect, so currently to do this in e.g. Python I first split the data:

```
test = 'Abc1/Def2/Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4'
strlist = re.split(r',', test)
result = ','.join([re.sub(r'\/', r'.', strlist[0])] + strlist[1:])
```

What I would prefer is to use a specific regexp pattern instead of Python-oriented solution though, so essentially I could have a `pattern` and `replacement` such that the following code would give me the same result:

```
result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, test)
```

Thanks for all regex-avoiding answers - I was wondering if I could do this using *only* regex (so e.g. I could use `sed` instead of Python).

Answer (score 3):

```
item = 'Abc1/Def2/Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4'
print item.replace("/", ".", item.count("/", 0, item.index(",")))
```

This will print what you need. Try to avoid regex wherever you can because they are slow.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with lookbehind expressions that look for both the beginning of the string and no comma.  Or don't use `re` entirely.

```
s = 'Abc1/Def2/Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4'

left,sep,right = s.partition(',')

sep.join((left.replace('/','.'),right))
Out[24]: 'Abc1.Def2.Ghi3,/Dore1/Mifa2/Solla3,Sido4'
```