# Regex to find words on strings that start with specific character, contains 2-5 characters and is not composed by only digits

Tags: java, regex, string, words

I can have one of the following sample strings:

1. Apple $Banana Kiwi
2. Apple $TTL, Kiwi
3. Apple $9999. Kiwi
4. Apple $9as. Kiwi
5. Apple $z.9s. Kiwi

I need to find the words contained by the string that start with '$' where lenght except '$' is between 2 and 5 and do not contains only digits and it can contains dots , without punctuation at end.

Inside the list above, number 2,4 and 5 match my criteria.

I tried to write a regex to do that without useful result.

```
(?<![a-z0-9])[$]{1}[A-Z0-9\.]{2,5}(?![a-z0-9])
```

I use Java to match regex

Is there a regex to do that?

Comment: post your attempts and also the language you're running.

Comment: Why has 3 failed.It has a `.` at end.So not only digits

Comment: it has exactly 5 chars like you said. Then why 3 got failed?

Comment: because contains only digit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match a specific character only if it is followed by string containing specific characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507756/how-to-match-a-specific-character-only-if-it-is-followed-by-string-containing-sp)

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookaround based regex like below.

```
(?<![a-z0-9])[$](?:(?!\d+\b)[A-Z0-9a-z.]){2,4}(?![a-z0-9])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO5zI3/4)

**OR**

```
(?<![a-z0-9])[$](?:(?!\d+\b)[A-Z0-9a-z]){2,4}(?![a-z0-9])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO5zI3/3)

Comment: I did not write , but the punctuation should not fall within the match. I have edited my question

Comment: Thanks! I get an update from my boss. Words can contains dot something like '$E.E..', match all except last dot . Can you help me?

Comment: i don't how many num of exact chars allowed? your question title says `2-5` but in your regex it's `2-4`. Explain this.

Comment: sorry, I did many tests , I have copied the wrong regex.I update it

Comment: @theShadow89 don't update your question over and over. Ask a new question if you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])\$(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,4}(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/15